# How can I get Bing to prefer Stack Overflow over garbage sites?

Tags: discussion, search, google, seo

In the past year or so, the number of garbage coding sites working their way up the search results from Google and Bing has really ballooned.  I often have to scroll down two or three pages past "expertcoderexchange.com" and "stackscraper.com" and so on to get to the Stack Overflow links I love so much.  While the core fault here seems to lie with the search providers, what can I do in the meantime to make my life better?

I know how to make Stack Overflow *be* the search provider for my browser bar (I haven't actually done this but I assume it's possible), but I don't want to go that far.

I'm interested in how to steer Bing and Google to prefer Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you specifically want to search Stack Overflow, why not add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your search string?

Comment: Good question - because I'm lazy.  Also I do like to get results for other sites, often official documentation, etc.

Comment: There are extensions that let you omit results by domain on all major search providers, but there's always some new scraper popping up.

Comment: Install uBlock Origin, and install [these filters](https://github.com/quenhus/uBlock-Origin-dev-filter). They're not completely up to date all the time either, but they're pretty efficient, and integrate conveniently with uBlock, which you really should have if you plan to browse the modern internet and _not_ go insane

Comment: "*I'm interested in how to steer Bing and Google to prefer S.O.*" 1. Buy both. 2. Make the adjustments you want.

Comment: On duckduckgo, you can simply add `!sod` to your search

Comment: uBlock Origin needs pretty expansive permissions.  Eg on Edge: "Read and change all data on all websites", "Change your privacy-related settings".    I get that it's open-source and good software, but I'm that paranoid.

Comment: I mean... it has to be able to see the html to see the html.

Comment: I guess I'll get used to adding `!sod` on duckduckgo or `site:stackoverflow.com` on the others when I want SO results, and searching again and wading through the scrapers when I want other stuff.

Comment: I'm sure it needs those permissions to do the job at hand.  I'm just not willing to pay that price.

Comment: It is a good thing to question the permissions a plugin requires, but when you're concerned about your data, why do you use Bing and Google? Sounds a bit counterproductive.

Comment: You know you can configure search engines, for example for chrome based browsers; https://superuser.com/a/1327513

Comment: I don't know about Bing, but the result of Google Search is *personalized*. The more you open SO from the result, the more often it will be suggested.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about how search engine websites work, rather than about Stack Overflow, and belongs on [webapps.se]

Comment: fair enough. I'll close it.  thanks all !

Comment: @Tom, search data privacy is one thing, but 'read and write all your data on all websites' goes a bit beyond that.

Comment: @orionelenzil I'm not sure how an adblock can work *without* reading and writing data. Also, Google has access to a lot more than just your search data. They'd be tracking you on websites you visit via the Google Analytics cookies and building up a profile from what you do, even if you never visit the search engine.

Comment: Can you add some example search queries?

Comment: `site:stackoverflow.com` works with [DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo). It presumably uses Bing underneath (*"It uses various APIs of other websites to show quick results to queries and for traditional links it uses the help of its partners (mainly Bing) and its own crawler ... It also partners with Bing, Yandex, and Wikipedia to produce results or make use of features offered."*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen the same query operator also works on StartPage. StartPage uses information search data from Google.

Comment: @orionelenzil Not paranoid at all - anyone who unquestioningly trusts the security of OSS after Heartbleed and Log4shell is just naive.

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Stand with Ukraine
yesterday: And [DirtyPipe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/DirtyPipe)

Answer (score 1):

Something to make clear:  so long as the other website abides by CC-by-SA and provides attribution (and links back) to the original question/answer, then *anyone* can repost Stack Overflow questions and/or answers.

To the direct question:  if you're having trouble getting exact results from Stack Overflow, use site:stackoverflow.com ([or !sod instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417649/how-to-get-bing-to-prefer-stack-overflow-to-garbage-sites#comment906461_417649)) to filter out non-Stack Overflow results.